# JQuery Element found but it's not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, element

Very strange... This page is something protected or anything i don't know?
I tried to click Next page anchor.

[image]

See [this page first.](https://www.karir.com/search?q=&sort_order=urgent_job&job_function_ids=&industry_ids=&degree_ids=-1&major_ids=&location_ids=&location_id=&location=&salary_lower=0&salary_upper=100000000&page=0&grid=list)

I tried to grab the element using this

```
var buttonNext = $('a.next-page');

if(buttonNext.length > 0){
    console.log('found!');

    // but when clicking still give the page not move or anything
    buttonNext.click();

    // or even no effect at all, same thing...
    buttonNext.trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have a click listener, it might be mousedown or something.

Comment: JS is probably being loaded before the element itself. you need to provide more details

Comment: i already wait for sometime,.... make a timeout and something,.. but the element is found. only the click is not giving me an expected result.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need to wrap `buttonNext` in `$()` again. Just call `buttonNext.click()`

Comment: you can try that too @Cerbrus,... it doesn't work. I mean it doesnt give error, but the clicking of jquery doesnt giving as equal as normal mouse click.

Comment: Try `$('a.next-page')[0].click()`

Comment: waaah... You're right @AdilLiaqat...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('a.buttonNext')` selector is an array of elements (all `a` elements with a `buttonNext` className), even if there is only one element it still return an array of one element, not the element it self.

I presume you have only one `buttonNext` element, in that case this should do the work

```
buttonNext[0].click();
```

Comment: Can you please check this as the accepted answer ... Thanks !